# How a Lambda in VPC can connect to Cloudsearch?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-vpc, vpc, amazon-cloudsearch

How a Lambda in VPC can connect to Cloudsearch? I don't see options to put Cloudsearch in VPC

Answer (score 2):

- You might need internet access to your VPC to connect to cloudsearch. So that your lambda can connect to aws cloudsearch. You can do that by associated your VPC must have a NAT gateway or NAT instance in a public subnet. [example](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/internet-access-lambda-function/).
- If you don't want to provide internet access to your VPC then you might need API Gateway and VPC Endpoints.
- You can configure your cloudsearch behind an API Gateway [aws docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloudsearch/latest/developerguide/api-gateway.html) and form the your VPC you can configure a VPC Endpoint [VPC Endpoint](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-endpoints.html) to connect to API Gateway. This would be utilizing the aws network.